# Bizarre "undefined method 'strftime' for 43200:Fixnum" in Rails controller test but works fine in actual view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, model-view-controller, tdd

I was working on a Rails application (version 4.2.0) and one part of the app involves displaying formatted dates in views. When I use the *strftime* method of a date to format in the view, everything works fine. However, one of the controller tests related to the views fails, saying that the *strftime* method doesn't exist for a "Fixnum", despite the fact that the property I run the method on is a date.

Specifically, in the **View** I have this:

```
...
<div><%= @meeting.date.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %></div>
...
```

The **Controller Test** has this:

```
  def setup do
    @person = persons(:bob)
    @meeting = meetings(:important)
  end
  ...
  test "should get show when logged in" do
    log_in_as(@person)
    get :show, id: @meeting.id  # Errors here
    assert_response :success
  end
```

The date property of the meeting model is a date (as expected):

```
create_table "meetings", force: :cascade do |t|
  ...
  t.date  "date"
  ...
end
```

Prior to the test, the @meeting variable is set to one of the fixtures in **meetings.yml**:

```
important:
  name: Important meeting
  date: 2015-06-24
  ...
  description: At this meeting, important things happen.
```

What is going on here? It's strange—the property works fine in the view and in rails console, but errors during the test which picks up the property as a Fixnum rather than a Date.

**Update**: Inspecting the meeting and its date gives the following:

```
puts @meeting.inspect
#<Meeting id: 92075913, name: "Important Meeting", date: "2015-06-24", ..., updated_at: "2015-06-24 22:13:43">

puts @meeting.date.inspect
# Wed, 24 Jun 2015
```

I need to resolve this issue soon as it's affecting me in multiple tests (controller and integration tests).

Comment: Can you include the code where you set the value of `@meeting`?

Comment: I've included the code.

Comment: Rails version?  Did you try using a Date object to_s(:db)?

Comment: In your setup action can you log out the value of `@meeting.inspect` and `@meeting.date.inspect`

Comment: I've logged the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a workaround for testing. Instead of defining fixtures in meetings.yml, I wrote a custom test helper method that generated some random meetings. Those random meetings had dates that worked just fine in the test.

Passing in things like `Date.now` into the Meeting constructor did give proper dates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use fixtures, but `date: 2015-06-24` probably isn't being converted to a proper Date object prior to being used.

Comment: Hmm. This would be interesting; the fixture was automatically generated with that date back when I created the meeting model.